# Send sms to different numbers based on the recipient Twilio and Contact form 7 - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twilio, contact-form-7

I'm working on integrating Twilio with Wordpress and Contact form 7 plugin.

I made a hook for Contact form 7 to send sms with Twilio on form submission. It works.

My next step is to send to different numbers based on the recipient ( I have 3 different location in the contact form 7 and the recipient changes based on the chosen location).

I can't make it work.

Below is my code, any thoughts?

1. This hook works and sends to 1 number only

   ```
   add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' );
   function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function() {
       $sid = 'xxx'; 
       $token = 'xxx'; 
       $client = new Client($sid, $token);  
       $to = '+1111111111';  


   $client->messages->create(
   // the number you'd like to send the message to
       $to,
       array( 
      'from' =>'+1212121211', 
      'body' => "form submitted"   
      )
   );
   }
   ```
2. This is the second part, I can't make it work.

   ```
   global $to;
   function wpcf7_do_something (&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {
       if ($WPCF7_ContactForm->mail['recipient'] = "bla@bla.com") {
           $to = '+1XXXXXXXXX';
       } else if($WPCF7_ContactForm->mail['recipient'] = "blabla@blabla.com") {
           $to = '+1x1x1x1x1x';
       } else {
           $to = "+1000000000"
       }
   }
   add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_do_something');

   add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' );

   function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function() {
       $sid = 'xxxxxxx'; 
       $token = 'xxxxxxx'; 
       $client = new Client($sid, $token);  



       $client->messages->create(
       // the number you'd like to send the message to
          $to,
          array( 
             'from' =>'+1XXXXXXXXX', 
             'body' => "form submitted"   
          )
       );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From what I can tell from other Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange questions, you actually get passed the form to the `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook, so you don't need the two hooks like you have been trying. Something like the following should work:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' );
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function($cf7form) {
    if ($cf7form->mail['recipient'] = "bla@bla.com") {
        $to = '+1XXXXXXXXX';
    } else if($cf7form->mail['recipient'] = "blabla@blabla.com") {
        $to = '+1x1x1x1x1x';
    } else {
        $to = "+1000000000"
    }

    $sid = 'xxx'; 
    $token = 'xxx'; 
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);  

    $client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
        $to,
        array( 
            'from' =>'+1212121211', 
            'body' => "form submitted"   
        )
    );
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.